# Shall I ask HR about the result of interview?

Tags: interviewing, indonesia

I am an intern who applied for full time job in some company in Indonesia. I already passed the online and offline test and after that I had an interview with psychologist 3 days ago. They say that I must wait for the result from the company (perhaps in email).

The question is, should I ask about the interview result? And when is the right time to ask about the result? Because I'm so curious about the result.

EDIT : it is banking industry

Comment: Which industry is this?

Comment: @SouravGhosh banking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do what they told you: wait. It can take some time to decide for a candidate, so wait at least a week. If you haven't heard from them then, you can send a polite inquiring e-mail asking when you can expect to hear from them. I know this time of waiting is hard, but they may have other candidates and you don't want to preassure them.

Comment: okay , i will wait at least two week , thankyou for the answer and advice

Comment: Maybe one week is enough, see edit

Comment: okay then , so i will contact her at tuesday

Comment: Normally you should wait about two days to accept an answer. Waiting to accept an answer invites other users to write answers as well, which might be better.

Comment: okay , thankyou again for the advice , sry i must learn about patience here ..

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention the associated industry, but the general turnaround time for interview result is somewhere between 3-5 days (It can vary based on location, industry type, specialization/ work domain etc.). If you do not get to hear by 5 (working) days, send a follow-up email as reminder, and if you have got the number of the recruitment contact (If it's HR that contacted you then HR, otherwise the contact for the recruitment team), you can call them up.

Not to be negative here, but if they seem to be stalling you, I'd advise not to expect too much out of this and keep looking elsewhere. If they get back, good. If they don't, you'll have other opportunities.

Comment: sry it is a banking industry

Comment: I updated to remove particular reference for software industry.

Comment: okay thankyou for the answer , because saturday and sunday is not office working hour , so i will try to contact in monday / tuesday

Answer (score 1):

While pushing for a result from an interview is more of an advanced move and I do not recommend for you to do it, there is one thing you absolutely can and should do - send a followup email thanking them for the interview!

It need not to be long, something akin to the following template:

> "[Whatever is correct greeting in your culture],
>
> I wanted to thank you for the opportunity to interview with you
>   yesterday, it was truly an eye-opener to learn about XYZ you've
>   mentioned, and to learn so much about your business, I had no idea
>   that CVM was so popular before! It was very educational indeed, and I
>   cannot wait to hope that we will have the opportunity to work together
>   soon.
>
> Best regards,"

Fill in the blanks and adjust the tone to match the one you had during the interview and off it goes. This will remind them that you exist, show that you were paying attention and is also a great time to address some gaps that may have come up during the interview,(like that mentioned XYZ which you absolutely didn't know about before, but have now educated yourself bout).

Answer (score 1):

> They say that I must wait for the result from the company (perhaps in
>   email).

Thus, you must wait.

Doing anything else would demonstrate that you aren't able to follow instructions.